# setInterval change Interval

Tags: javascript, setinterval, intervals

Hello I am new in javascript, I am making chrome extension, this extension contains the setInterval command, I want to change the time with javascript to the textbox I have added to a website. This change should remain when I refresh the page, how can I do this.

My content script start document_end

```
 var Refresh = setInterval(clickerStart,4000)
    function clickerStart(){
            var selection1 = document.querySelector("#\\30 ") !== null;
            if (selection1) {
            location.reload();
        } else {
            console.log("Islem Bulundu.");
            };
        }

      //textbox
      var Interval = document.createElement("INPUT");
      Interval.setAttribute("type", "text");
      Interval.setAttribute("value", " ");
      document.body.appendChild(Interval);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not handling with sensitive data, which I think it is the case, you can use localStorage or cookies to store and reuse data (the interval time) until the user returns to the page (after refreshing it or reopening it).

Here's an explanation on how to set cookies:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp